# Find the largest negative integer $x$ which satisfies the congruence $34x+6\equiv 2\pmod {20}$.

Tags: elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic

Find the largest negative integer $x$ which satisfies the congruence $34x+6\equiv 2\pmod {20}$.

I don't know how to deal with negative mods, could someone help me out here?

Comment: By "largest negative integer" do you mean the one nearest $0$?

Comment: Regardless...your congruence rearranges to $6x\equiv 4 \pmod {20}\implies 3x\equiv 2 \pmod {10}$ and that's easy to solve (by trial and error if nothing else).

Comment: @lulu  That helped alot, thanks!

Comment: @lulu You should write $\iff$. Otherwise you don't know if all the received solutions work on the original congruence.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$34x+6\equiv 2\pmod {20}\iff 34x+6=2+20y\iff 34x+4-20y=0$$
$$34x+6\equiv 2\pmod {20}\iff 17x-10y+2=0$$ A particular solution is $(x,y)=(-6,-10)$ hence all the solutions are given by 
$$\begin{cases}x=-6+10t\\y=-10+17t\end{cases}$$
Thus, if the largest negative integer $x$ it means the $x$ nearest to $0$ then $\color{red}{x=-6}$. Otherwise (if $|x|$ must be large) it does not exist beacause we can choose $t$ negative arbitrary.